# How to make a middle right header

Tags: css, reactjs, layout

I am trying to make a header.

The text is centered and then there is an image to the right. I've tried plain CSS and I've tried flexbox but cannot get the header to look right.

How do you make the header look like this?

Please see the image for desired design (ignore the vertical line above the "L").

[image: Header design]

```css
.header {
 background: #43e895;
 height: 10vh;
 width: 100vw;
 text-align: center;
}

.header-title {
 font-family: 'Avenir Next Demi Bold', 'Arial';
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.header-title {
 font-family: 'Avenir Next Demi Bold', 'Arial';
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.map-icon-container {
  float: right;
}

.map-icon {
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-title">Lunch Tyme</div>
    <div class="map-icon-container"><img src="map_icon" class="map-icon" alt="Map Icon"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you edit your code to include your existing CSS?

Comment: I have added my current code.

Comment: First thing that stands out, is `className` vs `class` on your two containers. Change that it appears ok?

Comment: text-align:center for h1 + position:absolute for the icon  would be the basic to start with. else , display can be also your friend (table/flex or grid).

Comment: Okay, fixed. I'm making this in React so that's why it's "className" instead of "class".

Comment: please add ReactJS tag to your question _ this will help to clarify the code requirements as well as future visitors with similar issues

Answer (score 0):

a few options :

- `text-align` + `position`

```css
.header {
 background:linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 50%, rgba(255,0,100,0.75) 50%)  #43e895;
 height: 10vh;
 width: 100vw;
 text-align: center;
}

.header-title {
 font-family: 'Avenir Next Demi Bold', 'Arial';
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding-top:10px;
}

.map-icon-container {
  position:absolute;
  right:1em;
  top:10px;
}

.map-icon {
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-title">Lunch Tyme</div>
    <div class="map-icon-container"><img src="map_icon" class="map-icon" alt="Map Icon"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- `display` + `:before`

  - A) `table`

```css
.header {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 100, 0.75) 50%) #43e895;
  height: 10vh;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.header-title {
  font-family: 'Avenir Next Demi Bold', 'Arial';
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
}

.container:before,
.map-icon-container {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 35px;
}

.map-icon {
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-title">Lunch Tyme</div>
    <div class="map-icon-container"><img src="map_icon" class="map-icon" alt="Map Icon" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- - B) `flex` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.header {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 100, 0.75) 50%) #43e895;
  height: 10vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.header-title {
  font-family: 'Avenir Next Demi Bold', 'Arial';
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
}

.container:before,
.map-icon-container {
  flex: 1;
  text-align:right
}

.map-icon {
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-title">Lunch Tyme</div>
    <div class="map-icon-container"><img src="map_icon" class="map-icon" alt="Map Icon" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- - C) `grid`  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
.header {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 100, 0.75) 50%) #43e895;
  height: 10vh;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.header-title {
  font-family: 'Avenir Next Demi Bold', 'Arial';
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
}

.map-icon-container {
  margin: auto 0 auto auto;
}

.map-icon {
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-title">Lunch Tyme</div>
    <div class="map-icon-container"><img src="map_icon" class="map-icon" alt="Map Icon" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

there is no one better than the other, the good one is the one that fits your needs and that you understand well enough to tune and reuse . Its up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Converted to Bootstrap and it got it done correctly.

HTML:

```
<div class="row flex-nowrap justify-content-between align-items-center header fixed-top">
  <div class="col-4 pt-1"></div>
  <div class="col-4 text-center">
    <div class="header-title">Lunch Tyme</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
    <div class="map-icon-container"><img src="map_icon" class="map-icon" alt="Map Icon"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
 background: #43e895;
 height: 10vh;
 width: 100vw;
 margin-left: 0;
}

.header-title {
 font-family: 'Avenir Next Demi Bold', 'Arial';
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.header-title {
 font-family: 'Avenir Next Demi Bold', 'Arial';
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.map-icon {
 width: 35px;
 padding-top: 5px;
}
```